# Does OOP violates the single responsibility principle?

Tags: c#, oop

Today I had an argument with someone.

I was explaining the benefits of having a rich domain model as opposed to an anemic domain model. And demoed my point with a simple class looking like that

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastname;
    }

    public string FirstName { get private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
    public int DaysOfHolidays { get; private set; }

    public void AddHolidays(int numberOfdays)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

As he defended his anemic model approach, one of his arguments was: "I am a believer in SOLID. You are violating the single responsibility principle as you are both representing data, and performing logic in the same class."

I found this claim really surprising, as following this reasoning, any class having one property and one method violates the SRP, and therefore OOP in general is not SOLID, and functional programming is the only way to heaven.

I decided not to reply to his many arguments, but I am curious what the community thinks on this question.

If I had replied, I would have started by pointing to the paradox mentioned above, and then  indicate that the SRP is highly dependent on the level of granularity you want to consider and that if you take it far enough,  any class containing more than 1 property or 1 method violates it.

What would you have said ?

Comment: This is primarily opinion based, but it feels a bit like a code smell to have a `AddHoliday` method on a class with a  `DaysOfHolidays` property. Why is DaysOfHolidays readonly ? Shouldn't that be a writable property with the business logic in `AddHoliday` contained in another class ?

Comment: This is better suited at Programmers.SE. Anyway "SOLID" does not mean "a class can contain either data or logic".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a design question, rather than a programming question.  Consider posting the question on programmers.stackexchange.

Comment: @servy Thanks that makes sense, didn't realize it. I'll post it there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single Responsibility Principle is only concerned with whether or not a particular piece of code (in OOP, typically we're talking about classes) has responsibility over one piece of *functionality*.  I think you're friend saying that functions and data can't co-mingle didn't really understand that idea.  If `Employee` were to also contain information about his workplace, how fast his car goes, and what type of food his dog eats then we'd have a problem.

Since this class deals only with an `Employee`, I think it's fair to say it doesn't violate SRP blatantly, but people are always going to have their own opinions.

One place where we might improve is to separate Employee information (like name, phone number, email) from his vacation.  **This in my mind doesn't mean that methods and data cannot co-mingle**, it just means that perhaps the vacation information could be in a separate place.

Answer (score 0):

To my mind this class could potentially violate SRP if it continued to represent both an `Employee` and `EmployeeHolidays`.

As it is, and if it came to me for Peer Review, I'd probably let it through. If more Employee specific properties and methods were added, and more holiday specific properties were added I would probably advise a split, citing both SRP and ISP.